# How to print user input in php docker?

Tags: php, docker

My dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
```

This is inside the `src/` folder

An `index.php`

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
label{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;}
</style>


<title>Add name</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" />
<br />

<input type="submit" value="Add name">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And just a `process.php` in the same `src/` folder

```
<?php

echo $_POST["first_name"];
```

I fill in a name, I submit but when I visit the process.php webpage it isn't showing the name I've submitted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anywhere where process.php is included or a request sent to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `action` of your form to the correct location.

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    // ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add process.php in **action** of the form

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
    //Form Fields
</form>
```